# Python: Numpy array, Take every 100th timepoint for each cell ID

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have the following problem. I have an array ( the first 3 element are x,y,z coordinates, the 4th element is the time and the 5th element is the cell ID (1-9). Now i just want every 50th or 100th element of every timepoint FOR EACH CELL ID. This is no duplicate question! So for cell ID 1 I want the row with timepoint 50,100,150 , for Cell ID2 the timepoint 50,100,150 and so on!

**Example array**

```
arr = np.array([['2.0', '29.0', '24.0', '0.0', '1'],
       ['0.0', '18.0', '4.0', '0.0', '2'],
       ['16.0', '9.0', '0.0', '9990.0', '7'],
       ['20.0', '23.0', '31.0', '9990.0', '8'],
       ['65.0', '30.0', '20.0', '0.0', '9']
       ['16.0', '9.0', '0.0', '9990.0', '9']])
```

Comment: Does your array really contain strings? If so, why?

Comment: You can convert it to a more useful type with `arr.view([('xyz', arr.dtype, 3), ('t', arr.dtype), ('cell', arr.dtype)]).squeeze(-1).astype([('xyz', float, 3), ('t', float), ('cell', arr.dtype)])`

Comment: So, for cell ID `9`, you would have two matches at timepoint `0`?

Comment: oh yes, sry bad example!, i edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this -

```
# Convert the fourth col to int type
a = arr[:,3].astype(float).astype(int)

steps = [15,50] # Define step intervals

# Get time-stepped array intervaled at either of the elements from steps
range_arr = np.arange(a.max()+1)
r = range_arr[((np.arange(a.max()+1)[:,None]%steps)==0).any(1)]

# Get mask of matches. Index into input array for final output.
out = arr[np.in1d(a,r)]
```

Comment: hmm, its strange but this gives me every 150th timestep

Comment: Ah i see my problem. My timesteps are in steps of 15

Comment: @Varlor Check out the edits to cover both 15s and 50s steps.